# SFDX Deploy taking too long in sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx

Everytime I run SFDX deploy to dev sandbox, it takes 1-3 minutes to complete. I'm making very simple changes VSCode.

What might be the root cause?
Where can I see the root cause?
If in logs, what kinds of things should I be searching for?

** Updates based on comments below **

I uninstalled Salesforce Extension Pack and then installed again.

I now get this in Terminal
sfdx version
›   Warning: sfdx-cli update available from 7.178.0 to 7.198.7.
sfdx-cli/7.178.0 darwin-x64 node-v18.12.0

I'm new to this sandbox. I'm not sure if they are using source tracking.

I am not running tests on Deploy.

I am not using VSCode's Deploy on Save feature. I was about a week ago, but turned it off. Back then, deploying to a different sandbox was working just fine.

Apex Settings > "Perform Synchronous Compile on Deploy" is already unchecked

Downgrading SFDC Extension Pack to v57.13.1 didn't speed up deployment

Comment: I suspect that including the version of the salesforce cli that you're using will be helpful (run `sfdx version` or `sf version`). As would knowing if you're using source tracking. Are you explicitly running any tests when you're doing these deployments?

Comment: sfdx version
 ›   Warning: sfdx-cli update available from 7.178.0 to 7.198.7.
sfdx-cli/7.178.0 darwin-x64 node-v18.12.0

Comment: I have Salesforce Extension Pack installed in VS Code. Is there a way to update that from the Extensions pane in VS Code?

Comment: For the pack, I found versions, and it shows I have the most recent: 57.15.0

Comment: Please [edit] that information into your question (along with the answers to the source-tracking and test execution questions).

Comment: Also, do you happen to have VSCode set up to deploy when you save changes to a file? If so, how often are you saving (and therefore deploying)? Does your first save go fast and then it slows down?

Comment: @DerekF Updated the question

Answer (score 2):

It could be the setting in your sandbox causing the slower deployments. Navigate to Setup --> Apex Settings --> Uncheck "Perform Synchronous Compile on Deploy"

Answer (score 0):

I tried downgrading my Salesforce Extension pack version in VS code from v57.15.0 to v57.13.1 worked.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).